# Run PS Script from workflow SP2013

Tags: 2013, workflow, powershell, script

I saw the great feature developed by iLoveSharePoint [here](http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/). But this is for **SP 2010**, and **2013** compatibility is not sure.

Have you heard about any other stuff to do the job ? ***Running powershell scripts from a workflow***.

Someone heard about [this](http://www.harepoint.com/Products/HarePointWorkflowExtensions/Default.aspx) before ? What about test ? Well this costs about 500€ and 1500€ ...

Comment: have you checked this, http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/458819-sp2013-workflow-to-invoke-powershell?

Comment: Yes, and they say "Execute SQL works in SharePoint 2013, but not the PowerShell bit". As it's a production server, I don't want to "test" things on it.

Comment: No one tried this solution within SharePoint 2013 ?

Comment: What are you looking for your PowerShell script to do? It may be that there is another way to accomplish your goal without using PowerShell. as out of the box it is not available.

Comment: I must be shy to explain what my ps script do. Because obviously, this can be done in JS or w/e. But as I'm not a developer at all... The script download all xml files (generated from forms) in a library, then read it and put it in another list, by filtering, and creating a calendar view. And I wanted user to refresh this new craeted list whenever they want, by cliking on a button or a link.

Comment: Do you think its possible (for a non-dev) to create a workflow that runs when an item in listA is updated, and get new info on this item, to update items in listB ? Question is : if listA is updated 15 times a day, the process will be huge, no ?

Comment: Edit : After researches, seems so much complicated compare to execute my PS script via scheduled tasks three times a day...